# In-bindings SQL query Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

Hi I am using Azure Functions In bindings SQL query with cosmos DB.
In SQL query I am using IN clause but I am getting the issue,

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "DatabaseName",
      "collectionName": "CollectionName",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmosDBConnection",
      "partitionKey": "/PartitionKey",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.email IN {emailList}",
      "direction": "in"
    }
]
```

I am using query-param in URL as

```
https://function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/TestFunction?emailList=("email1","email2")
https://function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/TestFunction?emailList=["email1","email2"] (test)
https://function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/TestFunction?emailList=(email1,email2)     (test)
```

But I am getting error in the response which is

```
"message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '@emailList'"
```

I am using HTTP Javascript function,

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    var inputDocument = context.bindings.inputDocument
    
    inputDocument.forEach(function(user) {
    context.log(user.email);
    });
    

    
    //context.bindings.userOutputDocument = inputDocument



    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: "Ok",
    };
};
```

Otherwise, I have to get all Documents from DB, which affects time complexity.
Regards,

Comment: please also post the config of your httpTrigger

Comment: I post the javascript-function and full JSON file, please let me know if anything else you want,

Answer (score 0):

You might have to include the `route` field in the httpTrigger config as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#customize-the-http-endpoint

Then you should be able to use the `email` param in your in-binding (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#using-route-parameters) for example).

Comment: thanks let me test with it, but with `route` can I get documents from an array. My problem is to get only documents which are in array or list of query param.